# Vector math arithmetic operations in jq

Tags: json, math, vector, jq, vector-multiplication

I'd like to perform vector math operations on a json array that stores numbers. In short how can we achieve one to one arithmetic operations by using jq?

I tried something with 'map' filter however could not achieved what I expect.

```
jq 'map(one-to-one)' <<< "{\"a\":[1,2], \"b\":[3,4]}"
```

or

```
jq 'map(one-to-one)' <<< "[[1,2],[3,4]]"
```

should produce

```
[3,8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problem, it makes sense to define a generic function:

```
# Input is assumed to be an array of two numeric arrays of the same length
def pairwise: transpose | map(.[0] * .[1]);
```

We can now easily use this in a variety of ways:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]] | pairwise

{"a":[1,2], "b":[3,4]} | [.a,.b] | pairwise

{"a":[1,2], "b":[3,4]} | [.[]] | pairwise
```

The result in each of these cases is of course `[3,8]`.

### Efficiency

For very large inputs, it might be worthwhile avoiding `transpose`:

```
def pairwise:
   .[0] as $x | .[1] as $y 
   | reduce range(0; $x|length) as $i ([]; . + [$x[$i] * $y[$i]]);
```

Typically with vectors one is interested in the inner product, which for efficiency would best be defined directly, e.g. as follows:

```
def inner($a; $b):
  reduce range(0;$a|length) as $i (0; . + $a[$i]*$b[$i]);
```

Comment: I do not even think about transpose in sense of computation time. Thanks for considerations and suggest alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

```
jq '. | transpose | map(reduce .[] as $item (1; . * $item))' <<< "[[1,2],[3,4]]"
```

Transpose gives us the elements that need to be multiplied together: `[[1, 3], [2, 4]]`. Then we can map each subarray to its product by using reduce.

The object version is just a bit different, as we need to get those values off of properties:

```
jq '[.[]] | transpose | map(reduce .[] as $item (1; . * $item))' <<< "{\"a\":[1,2], \"b\":[3,4]}"
```

Comment: Thank you Amadan, especially your updated answer is solves my problem.